# Compare two interfaces at runtime

Tags: typescript

I want to check if two interfaces are equal at runtime and then execute some code. I noticed a library conditional-type-checks that can compare types and returns a true or false type, but I am unsure of how to use it for my case.

This is what I have so far
`type IDialogUnchanged = IsExact<IDialog, IDialogOrig>;`

which returns a true or false type

Comment: Interfaces are [erased](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#what-is-type-erasure) at runtime.  So there's no way to do this with the type system.  You could compare two *values* (each of which is assignable to some interface, or some type you could possibly infer at design time), but without more information about your use case the only answer that could be given here is "no, sorry".

Comment: I'm trying to write a test in jest to check if two interfaces are equal, but now I realize I have to test for that at compile time. Do you know how I can do that? Should I make a new question about setting up typescript tests in jest?

Answer (score 3):

Short:
You can't. But they are hacks/workarounds/ways that can give you similar results, if you can change your requirements.

Long:
Interfaces doesn't exists at run-time, so there is no way you can extract data about its members and/or compare them. Interfaces are design time tools, for you, for auto-complete etc. They vanish on run-time. However, there are few other options.

1. You can emit types info and then retrieve it on run-time. I am not aware of any way to get full type info on runtime(like Java or C# reflection, but maybe some tools already exists). With [this package (reflect-metadata)](https://www.npmjs.com/package/reflect-metadata) you can emit constructor params types and then work with them.
2. If you have objects as instances of specific interfaces/classes, you can always compare them key by key, using **Object.keys(obj)** - it returns array of field names in given type(doesn't work with interfaces, as I mention, does not exist on runtime).
3. Also, **instanceof operator** may be the thing that you need. It will return true if an object is an instace of given class. If you will perform check for both types(say A and B) you want to compare (obj instanceof A && obj instanceof B), where B extends A and obj is of type B, you will get true as a result of this statement.

Hope you can work you way out. If not, please provide more details or provide that library's name. Regards.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I actually may be asking the wrong question. What I want is to write a test in jest that checks if two interfaces are equal, so what I probably need is guidance on writing a compile time test to work with typescript?

Comment: Are you using Webpack? How about writing a custom [loader](https://webpack.js.org/contribute/writing-a-loader/)? If you will introduce special naming(i.e. example.interface.ts) then you can write a loader that will export interface structure - then you can do the rest on run-time.

Comment: That's an interesting idea, I'm not too experienced with that. On another note, I found that the conditional-type-checks library I used can also assert if two types are equal and will raise a typescript compile error. I'd be content if it weren't for the fact that the errors only show up on build and not the jest testing report. And just to make my intention clear, I DO want it to show up in testing because the use case is to see if interface code is changed.

Comment: I'd go for the loader. You need almost no skill than pure brain-power and base js/nodejs knowledge. I already linked a tutorial in the comment above. Then all you have to do is to write your custom logic, that will parse the input file and export a proper module. In that way, you can generate any extra data you want. Had similar case, but not for unit tests, that was the perfect solution. It's easy, you can do it. But... I started to get suspicious. Why you just can't go with class/abstract class instead of an interface? And why you have 2 interfaces if you want them to be exactly the same?

Comment: My goal is to test whether the code for an interface has been changed, which means I need to compare it to an older version hand-typed. Do you think your solution will allow me to write assert statements in jest testing that run during runtime?

Comment: Yes, I am concerned. With loader, as I said, you are getting entire source file as plain text and you can export any structure you like. Also, this can be executed multiple times per single file. I imagine a case, where you write a loader that parses the interface file as text and exports some metadata from it - fields declared, their names and types. Since they will be exported, I see no trouble to test them during the runtime. That matches your goal I believe.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I ended up writing a little script to validate interface and function signatures from the source files instead.

Comment: The reason why I avoided looking further into the loader is because our senior dev deemed it unsuitable for our project. I don't believe we use webpack.